# Eclipse Neon does not save information about server

Tags: eclipse, macos-sierra, wildfly-10

here is the my steps.
 1: I create new server in eclipse.
 2: Choose Red hat Jboss Middleware.
 3: Install JBoss AS, Wildfly ...
 4: create new server and configure to my local wildfly server.
after restarting eclipse server disappears and if click to create new server eclipse again repeats step 1.
thanks in advance

Comment: I use MacBook Pro

Comment: Is anything else not being remembered? Which version of Eclipse is it? Installed how?

Comment: @nitind other thing are working properly till now.     version of eclipse eclipse-jee-neon-1a-macosx-cocoa-x86_64.    To install eclipse I just download from eclipse.org and unzip folder and thats all. thanks for replying by the way

Comment: @nitind I installed jboss tools from eclipse marketplace and every time after restarting my mac os Sierra it displays me this
"This wizard helps you to import and reinstall previously installed plug-ins. It is triggered because either you are launching eclipse for the first time or your Eclipse has been updated." I guess there was not problem with eclipse rather this is my Mac does smth wrong

Comment: You didn't install Eclipse under /Applications, did you?

Comment: I checked with eclipse-jee-mars-2-macosx-cocoa-x86_64 the result is the same. Sierra does smth wrong. can anyone help me

Comment: @nitind no just unzip it under downloads folder

Comment: @nitind how to install it under /Applications? it is .tar file do I need to copy it under /Applications
thanks

Comment: No, don't put it there. I'll have to see if Sierra does the same to me.

Comment: @nitind How are things going with ur Sierra? any ideas how to fix?

Comment: Could not reproduce; does it happen when you unpack just the download from eclipse.org? If not, it's worth reporting as a bug to JBoss Tools. Be sure to also look at the **Startup and Shutdown** preference page for anything that looks excessive.

Comment: @nitind I gave up and I am downgrading system to El Capitan.     thanks anyway